# Spring MVC REST and web.xml security-constraint problems

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, tomcat

I've implemented a REST service using Spring MVC 3.2. All the urls are secured using the standard security constraints with DIGEST authentication:

```
    <security-constraint>
        <web-resource-collection>
            <web-resource-name>Secure</web-resource-name>
            <url-pattern>/update/*</url-pattern>
        </web-resource-collection>
        <auth-constraint>
            <role-name>update</role-name>
        </auth-constraint>
    </security-constraint>

    <login-config>
        <auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>
        <realm-name>Secure</realm-name>
    </login-config>
```

I've only implemented GET, HEAD and OPTIONS operations so I want that all the remaining operations return a 405 - Request method not supported.

In theory, this is the default behaviour and it works if I don't protect the webapp with the security-contraint. However, with the protected webapp, the PUT and DELETE return a 403 and the PATCH operation a 501. The remaining operations work as expected.

Debugging I've seen that in these cases, the request doesn't reach the Spring DispatcherServlet so I guess that it has to be something weird with Tomcat. By the way, I'm using Tomcat 7 but I've seen the same behaviour with Tomcat 6.

Comment: The security constraint apply before the Dispatcher Servlet is reached, if you do an unauthorised PUT or DELETE a 403 forbidden is the expected outcome. You can add the HTTP Methods you want to protect to your web.xml file.  http://java.dzone.com/articles/understanding-web-security explains it. Or even have a look at http://software-security.sans.org/blog/2010/08/11/security-misconfigurations-java-webxml-files/

Comment: Yes, I know, but the problem is that it returns the 403 even if I provide the correct credentials (testing with SoapUI).

Comment: Add only the Web methods you want to protect to the `web-methods` i.e. `<http-method>HEAD</http-method>``<http-method>GET</http-method>``<http-method>OPTIONS</http-method>`